# Increase URI length limit or change the code for transferring big text

Tags: javascript, html, apache2, uri, php-5.5

I installed Apache2 server on linux Mint system to do some web development. I have a code where there is a text in `<pre>` tag. The php code makes a link to edit the text by transferring all text into edit page `<textarea>`.

The text transfers in URI. Well, as Apache has a URI length limit, I don't know how to transfer large amount of text. 
I searched and found out that there is a way to change this limit, but I couldn't find out where it is set. Also I read that it is not good to use long URIs.

So, I have to either increase the URI length limit or change my code. I haven't figured out how, though. This is the piece of page where text is (story.php, stored in $s variable):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php session_start() ?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>The story</title>
    <style>
        #story{border: darkolivegreen; border-style: solid ;border-width: 3px; padding: 10px }
        pre{white-space: pre-wrap}
        span{padding-right: 8px}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
include "navigation.php";
$id=$_GET['id'];
//ar_dump($id);
$mysql=new mysqli("",databaseuser,databasepassword,database);
$set=$mysql->query("select title,story,creator,dateCreated,identifier from Stories where identifier='$id'");
if( $set==false) echo $mysql->error;
$record=$set->fetch_array();
//var_dump($record);
if($record)
{
    $t=$record['title'];
    //check
    $s=htmlspecialchars_decode($record['story']);
    $c=$record['creator'];
    $time=$record['dateCreated'];
    $storyid=$record['identifier'];
    echo "<h1 id='heading'>$t</h1>";
    echo "<h2>By $c on $time</h2>";
    echo "<pre id='story' on>$s</pre>";
    if(isset($_SESSION[username]))
    $user=$_SESSION[username];

    $q="SELECT class FROM Accounts WHERE identifier='$user'";
    $result=$mysql->query($q);
    $group;
    if($res)
    {
        $group=$result->fetch_array()[0];
    }
    if(($user==$c && $group==users2) or $group==admins or $group==overseers)
    {
        $s=urlencode($s);
        $link='editstory.php?sid='.$storyid.'&text='.$s;
        echo "<a href='$link'>Edit</a>";
        //echo "<button data-storyid='$storyid' data-story='$s' onclick=''>Edit</button> ";
        echo "<button data-storyid='$storyid' onclick='deleteStory(this)'>Delete</button>";
    }
```

This is the page where text transfers into (editstory.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Editing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"
</head>
<body>
<?php
$storyid=$_GET['sid'];
$text=$_GET['text'];
$text=urldecode($text);
echo "<textarea id='text' rows='33' cols='200'>$text</textarea>
        <button data-sid='$storyid' onclick='updatestory(this)'>Save</button>
"
?>
<script>
    function updatestory(button) {
        var sid=button.getAttribute('data-sid')
        var text=document.getElementById('text')
        var value=text.value;
        console.log(text.value)
        var request=new XMLHttpRequest()
        request.onreadystatechange=function () {
            if(request.readyState==4)
            {
                window.location='story.php?id='+sid;
                console.log(request.responseText)
            }
        }
        request.open('POST','updatestory.php',true)
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send('sid='+sid+'&text='+value)
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to change my code, so I've increased URI length for now.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason to tamper with URI length.

You should instead send the story text data as HTTP POST message body, and the submission could be inside HTML form element.

See [W3 PHP5 Form Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)